# What is the best approach to display PySpark DataFrame without re-executing the logic each time we display?

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, caching, databricks, display

I have a PySpark DataFrame (defined in a notebook in Databricks) and different transformations are applied on the DataFrame. I want to display DataFrame after several transformations to check the results.

However, according to the [Reference](https://www.databricks.com/blog/2022/03/10/top-5-databricks-performance-tips.html), every time I try to display results, it runs the execution plan again. A solution has been proposed in the reference by saving the DataFrame and then loading it. However, this solution cannot be applied to the platform I am working on.

Is there any other solution to display results a few times in a notebook without re-executing the logic?

Can I use .cache() for this purpose as below:

```
df.cache().count()
df.display()
```

However, I am not still sure that using caching avoids recomputing the entire transformations.

Another solution is introduced in the [Reference](https://towardsdatascience.com/best-practices-for-caching-in-spark-sql-b22fb0f02d34):

```
When you cache a DataFrame create a new variable for it cachedDF = df.cache().
This will allow you to bypass the problems that we were solving in our example, that sometimes it is not clear what is the analyzed plan and what was actually cached. 
Here whenever you call cachedDF.select(…) it will leverage the cached data.
```

I didn't understand well the logic behind it and whether it helps to avoid recomputing the entire transformations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dataframes in Spark are immutable and `cache` method is no exception - it does not make the dataframe cached - instead it returns the cached dataframe, exactly as in the reference you quoted:

```
cachedDF = df.cache()
```

So when you ran `df.display()` - you are displaying the original uncached dataframe, not the cached one.

You need to write:

```
cachedDF = df.cache()
cachedDF.count()
cachedDF.display()
```

in order to run `count()` and `display()` both on the cached dataframe.

Note that the only way to benefit from caching is to save the reference to cached dataframe in a variable. This would still be wrong:

```
df.cache().count()
df.cache().display()
```

It would cause - exactly as written - calculation of df, caching it, then count, and after that once more recalculation of df, cache again, then display.